# Why i can't get parameters from the url sent by Facebook after '#' character

Tags: java, facebook

I'm trying to make login to facebook according to Facebook Server-Side Authentication flow using jsp and servlets.
I was succsessfuly login to my fb account but when fb is redirecting to my app, it sends the parameters (state...) after the character '#'.
I was looking at this: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4144878/get-url-parameters-after-in-java.

but i'm doing it in a different way then they do.

here's my code:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=343473222406382" +
                "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/accountsLogger&response_type=token&state=logged"));
```

and i'm redirecting to:

```
{http://localhost:8080/accountsLogger/#state=logged&access_token=AAAE4YxdpUO4BAILjJoj5GsFZBDir1YmZCy4ZC9BmZAOCAztC2QclKo46OSce7dzObL6lSzrYpRDgQycOzzhfbqThR6kVC16lmurC5X5oV1lIrsvI0h9D&expires_in=4329.}
```

Answer (score 2):

The FB API is built (largely) to be used client-side. The hash-portion of the URL (what is after the '#') is never sent to the server by the browser (which is why you can't pick it up). If you need this information server-side, you need to pick it up using javascript on your accountsLogger page (`document.location.hash`), convert the "hash parameters" into "regular" url-parameters on another URL and redirect the page to that URL.

Answer (score 1):

URL after `#` is not sent to the server. It's originally intended as an anchor, it is, something to refer on the downloaded page. The browser then do:

```
GET /your/url.htm?param1=value&param2=value
```

and if there's `#someanchor` at the end the browser tries to position the page to make that anchor visible (if it exists).

Old school anchor:

`<a name="someanchor">Hello</a>`

Standard HTML anchor:

`<p id="someanchor">Hello</p>` (thanks @Jon Hanna)

Comment: Or `<p id="someanchor">The paragraph we're interested in</p>`. After 13 years, I think we're safe not worrying about older browsers that don't support ìd` any more.

Comment: Oh! +1 I didn't know about id working as an anchor. Great! (that explain why # is used for id's on CSS selectors :)

Comment: `id` is the universal way to identify a fragment of an HTML document for any reason, since 4.01. `name` on anchor elements are in the same namespace (if you use an id, you can't use the same for a name on an `<a>`), but are really just for backwards-compatibility with browsers earlier. Since I remember NS4 and IE4 both supporting `id`, and indeed any that supports CSS must do, I wouldn't worry about that compatibility any more! `id` is nicer because it can cover any element, among other things.

Comment: Yep. I know about id, just didn't know good ol'HTML anchor was linked to id and `a@name` was thing from the past :)